# Dependency conflict between python-telegram-bot, httpx, and googletrans

Tags: python, fastapi, telegram-bot, google-translation-api, fastapi-middleware

I am facing a dependency conflict issue while trying to install or upgrade the python-telegram-bot, httpx, and googletrans libraries in my Python project. The error message indicates that there is an incompatibility between the required versions of httpx for python-telegram-bot and googletrans.

The specific versions I am dealing with are:

- python-telegram-bot version 20.7 requires httpx~=0.25.2.
- googletrans version 4.0.0rc1 requires httpx==0.13.3.

When I attempt to upgrade httpx to version 0.25.2 as required by python-telegram-bot, it causes a conflict with the version required by googletrans.

I have tried the following steps, but the issue persists:

```
pip install --upgrade httpx==0.13.3
pip install --upgrade googletrans==4.0.0rc1
pip install --upgrade python-telegram-bot
```

The error message mentions an inability of pip's dependency resolver to account for all installed packages and attributes this to the source of the conflict.

1. How can I resolve this dependency conflict between python-telegram-bot, httpx, and googletrans to ensure compatibility?
2. Are there specific versions of these libraries that are known to work well together?
3. Is there an alternative approach or workaround to install these libraries without encountering the conflict?

Comment: Seeing as the last release for googletrans were over three years ago and nothing has been released for the rc1 version since then, I guess copying the project into your own repository if allowed by their license (and your license) and changing the dependencies yourself is probably the most realistic solution

Comment: Ok bro. I will consider your point